# Replacing &#xD; with <br> before printing XML contents using SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, replace, simplexml, newline

I know it's probably a very simple issue but still I didn't find a solution...
Ok, I'll be brief:
suppose to have a so structured XML file:

```
<root><item><text>blah blah blah&#xD;blah blah blah&#xD;blah blah blah&#xD;...</text></item></root>
```

My XML is obviously more complex but that's not important since my question is:
how do I replace those `&#xD;` with, for instance, html `<br>` tags?

I'm using SimpleXML to read data from XML and tried with:

```
echo str_replace("&#xD;", "<br>", $message->text);
```

and even with:

```
echo str_replace("\n", "<br>", $message->text);
```

but nothing...

I need to use SimpleXML for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`&#xD;` represents the ASCII "carriage return" character (ASCII code `13`, which is `D` in hexadecimal), sometimes written `"\r"`, rather than the "linefeed" character, `"\n"` (which is ASCII `10`, or `A` in hex). Note that when SimpleXML is asked for the string content of a node (with `(string)$node` or implicitly with statements like `echo $node`) it will turn this "entity" into the actual character it represents.

Depending on your platform (Windows, Linux, MacOS, etc), the standard line-ending, accessible via the built-in constant `PHP_EOL`, will be either `"\n"`, `"\r\n"`, or `"\r"`.

The safest way to replace these with HTML linebreak tags (`<br>`) is to replace *any* of these characters, since you don't know which convention the *source* of the XML data might have been using.

PHP has a built-in function which should be able to do this for you, called [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/nl2br). If you want a slightly custom version, there's a comment in the docs from "ngkongs" showing how to use `str_replace` to similar effect.

Comment: So `echo nl2br($message->text);` would be a better solution here, and it seems definitely the best solution too. I'm going to upvote and accept yours as the answer to my question.

Comment: Please do not miss http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-white-space and *2.11 End-of-Line Handling* which directly follows on that link.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out how to solve just before posting my question so, having already written, I'll share this hoping it'll be useful for someone else sooner or later...

This does the trick:

```
echo str_replace(PHP_EOL, "<br>", $message->text);
```

Comment: If someone thinks there would be a better solution for this please tell me

Comment: That will only work if your platform's definition of line ending (`PHP_EOL`) happens to match the platform the XML was generated on.