# How to handle ParseError while reading Large XML file?

Tags: python, pandas, xml, bigdata

I am learning some begineer level bigdata and trying to read large xml files to convert them to pandas DataFrame using ElemetTree Iterparse however I got an ParserError about invalid character

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

def read_xml(filepath,tag,*args):
    atts=[arg for arg in args]
    dict_list = []
    
    for _, elem in et.iterparse(filepath, events=("end",)):

        tempdict={}
        
        if elem.tag == tag:
            for i in range(len(atts)):
                tempdict[atts[i]]=elem.attrib[atts[i]]
        
            dict_list.append(tempdict)
            elem.clear()

    return pd.DataFrame(dict_list)
```

When I check the some lines near the exception I got this:

[image]

and I suppose the problem is about those characters `&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA`

this answer explain what those characters mean, but still I dont know how to solve it.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15722541/5711393

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with the XML you've shown us.

Comment: That reference to column 5445 suggests something else is going on here.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue with lxml library

```
from lxml import etree

def read_xml(filepath,tag,*args):
    #my_parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True)
    atts=[arg for arg in args]
    dict_list = []
    
    for _, elem in etree.iterparse(filepath, events=("end",),recover=True):

        tempdict={}
        
        if elem.tag == tag:
            for i in range(len(atts)):
                tempdict[atts[i]]=elem.attrib[atts[i]]
        
            dict_list.append(tempdict)
            elem.clear()

    return pd.DataFrame(dict_list)
```